# Inserting Python List to Pandas dataframe rows and setting row values to NaN

Tags: python, pandas

Pandas way of inserting python list into specific Pandas dataframe column as new rows. After inserting, fil in the remaining values as NaN.

For example, the list appears simlar to the below:

```
list_dates = ['2021-12-01', '2021-12-02', '2021-12-03', '2021-12-06', '2021-12-08']
```

The Pandas Dataframe appears as:

```
df_sentiment.iloc[10:20, : 10]

ticker      AAPL.OQ ABBV.N      ABT.N       ACN.N   ADBE.OQ     AIG.N       AMD.OQ  AMGN.OQ     AMT.N   AMZN.OQ
Date                                        
2021-11-24  NaN     NaN         NaN         NaN     NaN         NaN         NaN     0.632792    NaN     NaN
2021-11-25  NaN     0.211714    NaN         0.846193    0.210173    NaN         NaN     0.043700    NaN     NaN
2021-11-26  NaN     0.115301    -0.629839   NaN     0.081402    -0.287198   NaN     NaN            -0.448907 NaN
2021-11-27  NaN     NaN         0.384544    NaN     0.490425    -0.003641   0.253752    NaN             NaN     NaN
2021-11-28  NaN     NaN         0.036393    NaN     0.003484    NaN         NaN     0.056091    NaN     NaN
2021-11-29  0.163266 -0.165520  0.149920    NaN     -0.014639   -0.448595   0.097651    0.381039    0.058590 -0.016986
2021-11-30  NaN     NaN         NaN         NaN     NaN         NaN         NaN     NaN         NaN     0.557565 
2021-12-07  NaN     NaN         NaN         0.097732    NaN         NaN         NaN     NaN         NaN     NaN
2021-12-09  NaN     NaN         NaN         NaN     NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN     NaN
2021-12-10  NaN     NaN         NaN         NaN     NaN         NaN         NaN     NaN         NaN     NaN
```

Desired update, from appending list to Date column and setting remaining values of rows where list values inserted into "Date" column to NaN, would look like df_sentiment:

```
df_sentiment.iloc[10:20, : 10]
ticker      AAPL.OQ ABBV.N      ABT.N       ACN.N   ADBE.OQ     AIG.N       AMD.OQ  AMGN.OQ     AMT.N   AMZN.OQ
Date                                        
2021-11-24  NaN     NaN         NaN         NaN     NaN         NaN         NaN     0.632792    NaN     NaN
2021-11-25  NaN     0.211714    NaN         0.846193    0.210173    NaN         NaN     0.043700    NaN     NaN
2021-11-26  NaN     0.115301    -0.629839   NaN     0.081402    -0.287198   NaN     NaN            -0.448907 NaN
2021-11-27  NaN     NaN         0.384544    NaN     0.490425    -0.003641   0.253752    NaN             NaN     NaN
2021-11-28  NaN     NaN         0.036393    NaN     0.003484    NaN         NaN     0.056091    NaN     NaN
2021-11-29  0.163266 -0.165520  0.149920    NaN     -0.014639   -0.448595   0.097651    0.381039    0.058590 -0.016986
2021-11-30  NaN     NaN         NaN         NaN     NaN         NaN         NaN     NaN         NaN     0.557565 
2021-12-01  NaN     NaN         NaN         NaN     NaN         NaN         NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
2021-12-02  NaN     NaN         NaN         NaN     NaN         NaN         NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
2021-12-03  NaN     NaN         NaN         NaN     NaN         NaN         NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
2021-12-06  NaN     NaN         NaN         NaN     NaN         NaN         NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
2021-12-07  NaN     NaN         NaN         0.097732    NaN         NaN         NaN     NaN         NaN     NaN
2021-12-08  NaN     NaN         NaN         NaN     NaN         NaN         NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
2021-12-09  NaN     NaN         NaN         NaN     NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN     NaN
2021-12-10  NaN     NaN         NaN         NaN     NaN         NaN         NaN     NaN         NaN     NaN
```

I've tried append and concat, but haven't been able to get it right or have been getting errors.

Comment: Are you just trying to fill in the missing days? e.g. `df.asfreq("D")` (assuming `Date` is a date index)

Answer (score 1):

In order to append a new row with just the ticker date you can do the following.

```
# this creates a list of NAN values minus 1 (due to the date)
to_append = [np.NAN] * df_sentiment.shape[1] - 1

# we set the index to the date column so we can append using the loc method
df_sentiment = df_sentiment.set_index("Date")

# iterate over the list dates and append them to your data frame
for date in list_dates:
    df_sentiment.loc[date] = to_append

# move the date column back into the dataframe
df_sentiment = df_sentiment.reset_index()
```